# cannot find or load main class when run a jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Firstly, I know this problem is asked frequently. But My problem is different, so please be patient to see the full description.

I have utilized intellij IDEA 2018.2 to build the jar. I have ever built the jar with 2017 and it worked fine. Recently, I have used intellij to build the jar with artifact. [image]

And the setting seems to be fine. It worked for me before. But I ran the built jar, it indicated that "the main class cannot be run or loaded".

The jar file seems normal. But I found the META-INF is different. I have some files are strange:
[image]

I find if I delete these files except MANIFEST.MF. It can work fine. I am not sure what's the difference of the settings.

I have tried the below methods:

1. Try to delete the .idea folder, and open the project.
2. Try to remove the artifact and configure a new one.
3. Try to modify the output path of module.
4. Rebuild the project or rebuild the artifact jar.

But all the methods cannot work. And I have tried to build the jar with the same settings in both MAC OS and windows OS in intellij, but the result seem to be same. Can any one provide me with some suggestions. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `*,RSA, *.SF, *.DSA` are files that are created when the jarfile is signed. Apparently, the jars that you use are signed and so if you extract the contents and place them in a new jar, the signature is invalid and Java won't accept them. So you should either remove the signatures, or resign the entire jar that your artifact produces.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there anyway to resign the entire jar by arifact setting in intellij? And I wonder if there is do something with the version of the intellij. I remember that the intellij 2017 would not resign the jar built.

Comment: These files are not there because of a re-sign action by IntelliJ. If you open up your library jars, you'll see that the libraries themselves are signed. IntelliJ just unpacks them and adds the content to your final artifact. To resign the jar you would need a code signing certificate and a post-processing task from for example Ant using the `signjar` element. If you don't want to sign, you might want to unsign the libraries. You can extract it, delete the `*,RSA, *.SF, *.DSA` files and repack it again using your favourite zip-tool.

Comment: It does not make sense. As the same project with the same dependencies. And I tried to build the jar with intellij 2018 ultimate version and intellij 2017 community version. I found that the jar built by community version is ok. There are not any `*.RSA,*,SF,*.DSA` files.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that what is solution for this. I should not import the dependencies as a folder. I have to import them by select all the jar files instead of the folder of the jar files.